# Best way to intercept XHR request on page with Puppeteer and return mock response

Tags: automated-tests, puppeteer

I need to be able to intercept XHR requests on page loaded with [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) and return mock responses in order to organize backendless testing for my web app. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well. In the newest puppeteer,it provide the `request.respond()` method to handle this situation.

Comment: Great to see that it's now implemented. Marked this as an accepted answer.

Comment: There is [pptr-mock-server](https://github.com/getdock/pptr-mock-server) available now to accomplish this. Internally it relies on request interception and [request.respond()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestrespondresponse) method. Library is pretty minimal, and may not fit everyone's needs, but it at least provides an example how to implement backendless testing using Puppeteer.

Comment: there is a **NOTE** in [doc](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.6.0&show=api-requestrespondresponse) says "mocking responses for dataURL requests is not supported. calling `request.respond` for a dataURL request is a noop"

Answer (score 38):

It seems that the way to go is `request.respond()` indeed, but still, I couldn't find a concrete example in the web on how to use it. The way I did it was like this:

```
// Intercept API response and pass mock data for Puppeteer
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', request => {
    if (request.url() === constants.API) {
        request.respond({
            content: 'application/json',
            headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
            body: JSON.stringify(constants.biddersMock)
        });
    }
    else {
        request.continue();
    }
});
```

What happens here exactly?

1. Firstly, all requests are intercepted with `page.setRequestInterception()`
2. Then, for each request I look for the one I am interested in, by matching it by URL with `if (request.url() === constants.API)` where `constants.API` is just the endpoint I need to match.
3. If found, I pass my own response with `request.respond()`, otherwise I just let the request continue with `request.continue()`

Two more points:

- `constants.biddersMock` above is an array
- CORS header is important or access to your mock data will not be allowed

Please comment or refer to resources with better example(s).

Comment: This is a correct way of doing this. However `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is optional and depends on particular setup.

Comment: Thanks a lot for confirming this!

Comment: Note, [request.url](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requesturl) is a function, so should be `request.url() === constants.API`

Comment: Nice catch. Updated!

Comment: I think the `content: 'application/json',` key should be `contentType: "application/json"`. [Docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#httprequestrespondresponse-priority)

Answer (score 7):

If anyone is interested I ended up creating special app build for my testing needs, which adds [Pretender](https://github.com/pretenderjs/pretender) to the page. And I communicate with Pretender server using Puppeteer's `evaluate` method.

This is not ideal, but I couldn't find a way to achieve what I need with Puppeteer only. There is a way to intercept requests with Puppeteer, but seems to be no way to provide fake response for a given request.

**UPDATE:**

As X Rene [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46880938/434402) there is now native support for this in Puppeteer v0.13.0 using [request.respond()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestrespondresponse) method. I'm going to rewrite my tests to use it instead of Pretender, since this will simplify many things for me.

**UPDATE 2:**

There is [pptr-mock-server](https://github.com/getdock/pptr-mock-server) available now to accomplish this. Internally it relies on request interception and [request.respond()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestrespondresponse) method. Library is pretty minimal, and may not fit your needs, but it at least provides an example how to implement backendless testing using Puppeteer. Disclaimer: I'm an author of it.

Comment: do you have some examples on how to use pptr-mock-server?

Comment: @Tomazini I planned to work on documentation and some examples next week. Will add to the repository readme.

Comment: tks, I'm gonna keep track of the repository... my problem is with resquest.respond method, the response is not getting processed by the app

Answer (score 4):

I created a library that uses Puppeteer's `page.on('request')` and `page.on('response')` to record and respond with mocked requests.

https://github.com/axiomhq/puppeteer-request-intercepter

```
npm install puppeteer-request-intercepter
```

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const { initFixtureRouter } = require('puppeteer-request-intercepter');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Intercept and respond with mocked data.
  const fixtureRouter = await initFixtureRouter(page, { baseUrl: 'https://news.ycombinator.com' });
  fixtureRouter.route('GET', '/y18.gif', 'y18.gif', { contentType: 'image/gif' });

  await page.goto('https://news.ycombinator.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
  await page.pdf({ path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'A4' });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try out [Mockiavelli](https://github.com/hltech/mockiavelli) - request mocking library for Puppeteer. It was build exactly for backendless testing of webapps. It integrates best with jest and jest-puppeteer, but works with any testing library.