# How to get Puppeter to intercept requests that were intiated by 3rd party scripts?

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

Im building a script which is to intercept all Google Analytics pageview hits from a site, and it works fine for most requests, but I have one type where a 3rd party script injects this tag below and the pageview-call very late in the loading process, and Puppeter doesn't seem to recognize these requests even though Chrome devtools show them.

Edit: it's not just the GA pageview hit that Puppeter is missing, it's several requests that are made at the end of loading.

```
<script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
```

Any ideas on how I can get Puppeteer to show me all requests?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to intercept XHR request on page with Puppeteer and return mock response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365972/best-way-to-intercept-xhr-request-on-page-with-puppeteer-and-return-mock-respons)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setRequestInterception` method to block scripts the page is making regardless of who initiated. There's a great example here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue