# Puppeteer request interception best practice for multiple responses to the same endpoint

Tags: javascript, jestjs, coded-ui-tests, puppeteer

For my unit tests I intercept all requests and then responding with mocked date for specific endpoints. I have a `pageMockedRequests` function that will switch on the endpoint.

My issue comes when I want to change the response I am sending back depending on how many times it has been called.

```
    const pageMockedRequests = (request) => {
      switch (request.url()) {
        case ENDPOINTS.A:
          return request.respond(jsonResponseWrapper(returnValidToken(), 200));
        case ENDPOINTS.B:
          if (count === 0) {
            return request.respond(jsonResponseWrapper({RESPONSE FOR 1st CALL}, 200));
          } else if (count === 1) {
            return request.respond(jsonResponseWrapper({RESPONSE FOR 2nd CALL}, 200));
          }
        default:
          return request.abort();
      }
    };
```

The above shows that `ENDPOINT.B` for the second time will be different from the first response. I'm currently changing it on `count`.

Is anyone else doing this differently?

Answer (score 0):

Using a count seems okay for this implementation. How many different possibilities are there? If you only have two options, simplify it:

```
let isFirstCall = true;

const pageMockedRequests = (request) => {
  switch (request.url()) {
    case ENDPOINTS.A:
      return request.respond(jsonResponseWrapper(returnValidToken(), 200));
    case ENDPOINTS.B:
      if (isFirstCall) {
        isFirstCall = false;
        return request.respond(jsonResponseWrapper({/* RESPONSE FOR 1st CALL */}, 200));
      }

      return request.respond(jsonResponseWrapper({/* RESPONSE FOR 2nd CALL */}, 200));

    default:
      return request.abort();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mockiavelli](https://github.com/hltech/mockiavelli) request mocking library for Puppeteer. Its **One-time mocks** feature (https://github.com/hltech/mockiavelli#one-time-mocks) allows to define different responses for 1st and 2nd call.

Comment: I notice you've posted this same recommendation for a library you've contributed to on a few different answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61736721/6243352) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61737073/6243352). See [this meta thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298734/is-it-acceptable-to-promote-my-own-library-as-part-of-a-real-answer) which explains that the answer needs to actually answer the question and disclose your affiliation, neither of which was done on these posts.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerating every case with an `if` or `switch` is fine when there's only a couple of possibilities. But when you wind up with more than 3 or 4 options, the [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) increases beyond maintainability.

A scalable approach uses a data structure that is basically a lookup table for all of your request parameters. One approach is to use a nested object keyed by URL. Each URL points to an inner object keyed by method which keys to an array of responses. For each response array, you could keep an index counter that steps forward whenever responses are sent, or mutate the array by popping or shifting.

Here's a sketch of this approach:

```
const responsesByEndpoint = {
  "https://www.example.com/api/users": {
    GET: [/* mocked responses */],
    POST: [/* mocked responses */],
    PUT: [/* mocked responses */],
    DELETE: [/* mocked responses */],
  },
  "https://www.example.com/api/posts": {
    GET: [/* mocked responses */],
    POST: [/* mocked responses */],
  },
  "https://www.example.com/api/login": {
    POST: [/* mocked responses */],
  },
  // ...
};

page.on("request", request => {
  try {
    const response = responsesByEndpoint
      [request.url()][request.method()].shift()
    ;
    
    if (response === undefined) {
      throw Error;
    }

    request.respond(response);
  }
  catch (err) {
    request.abort(); // or: request.continue();
  }
});
```

The data structure of responses by endpoint and method is regular and can be serialized as an external file, although you may need to add `body: async () => ({"your": "body"})` functions per response before use during deserialization.

This approach also nicely handles bad requests without changing any code or adding to your `switch` or `if`-`else` chain.

If you need to reset your mocks occasionally, use your test runner's `beforeEach` block or write a function that returns it fresh.

Even if you're not using this exact mocking approach, this pattern is generic and should save you from `if`/`switch` sadness.